# Relation OR between meta and tax query in wordpress

Tags: sql, wordpress, meta, tax

I have a problem with my WordPress query. I know that I can't set OR relation between tax query and meta query in WP Query so I have to write my custom SQL query.

I need to show posts which have category from array categories OR have the same value from the custom field.

My code:

```
global $wpdb;
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category();
$locations = get_field('connect_post_to_a_location');
$location_array = [];
$category_array = [];
if (!empty( $categories )) :
    foreach($categories as $category):
        $category_array[]=$category->term_id;
    endforeach;
endif;

if( !empty($locations) ):
    foreach( $locations as $location ):
        $location_array[] = $location;
    endforeach;
endif;
```

Below there is wp query but it doesn't work, because I can't set OR relation between tax query and meta query.

```
$args = (
    array (
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post__not_in' => array($id),
        'orderby'        => 'date',
        'order'          => 'DESC',

    )
);

if(!empty($category_array)) {
    $args['tax_query'] =  array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $category_array
        )
    );
}

if ( !empty($location_array) ) {
    $meta_arr = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
    );
    foreach($location_array as $value){
        $meta_arr[] = array(
            'key' => 'connect_post_to_a_location',
            'value' => serialize(strval($value)),
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        );
    }
    $args['meta_query'] = $meta_arr;
}
```

and now I have to convert my WP QUERY to Custom query but I don't know how can I do this. I wrote the only simple query and it works, but I need to add tax and meta query, so please give me any advice or examples. Thanks!

```
global $wpdb;
global $post;

$querystr = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.*
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
";

$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

if ($pageposts):
    foreach ($pageposts as $post):
        setup_postdata($post);
?>
        <div>
        //some code
        </div>
<?php
    endforeach;
endif;`enter code here`
```